# Como utilizar uma coleção como elemento de uma array em Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto usando scikit-learn (e pandas para lidar com os dados) para prever os resultados de jogos de futebol baseado em resultados anteriores. Como metodologia do projeto, para cada linha do conjunto de dados utilizada na predição, o resultado é determinando usando como base os três últimos jogos dos times, que eu coloquei em uma array do NumPy. Eu obtive um erro quando utilizei a tento adicionar o conjunto com os três últimos jogos ao dataset do pandas que será utilizado na classificação.
O código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

ds_resultados = pd.read_csv("E0_new2.csv")

ds_resultados["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(ds_resultados.Date)

data = ds_resultados[["FTHG", "FTAG", "HTHG", "HTAG", "HS", "AS", "HST", "AST"]]
target = ds_resultados["FTR"]

#CÓDIGO PARA PEGAR OS TRÊS ÚLTIMOS RESULTADOS PARA CADA JOGO

cont = 0;

for index, row in ds_resultados.iterrows():
    auxHome = ds_resultados[((ds_resultados["HomeTeam"] == row["HomeTeam"])
    | (ds_resultados["AwayTeam"] == row["HomeTeam"]))]
    auxHome = auxHome[auxHome["Date"] < row["Date"]].sort_values(by="Date", ascending=True).head(n =                 3)

listaTarget = np.array([]).astype('int64')

if auxHome.shape[0] == 3:
    for i in range(0, 3):
        linha = auxHome.iloc[i]

        listaTarget = np.append(listaTarget, linha["FTR"])

    data = data.append(row[["FTHG", "FTAG", "HTHG", "HTAG", "HS", "AS", "HST", "AST"]])

    target = target.append(pd.Series([]), ignore_index = True)
    target.at[cont] = listaTarget #linha que, quando executada, gera o erro
    cont = cont + 1
```

Quando a linha

```
target.at[cont] = listaTarget
```

é executa, eu obtenho o seguinte erro

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Se for necessário, deixo abaixo o conjunto de dados (E0_new2.csv) utilizado com as devidas legendas (a coluna "FTR" é utilizada como variável *target*, coloquei ela no conjunto de dados apenas para fins de explicação):

```
   print(data.head(n=10))
      FTHG  FTAG  HTHG  HTAG  HS  AS  HST  AST  FTR
   0     2     1     1     0   8  13    6    4    1
   1     2     0     1     0  12  10    4    1    1
   2     0     2     0     1  15  10    6    9   -1
   3     0     3     0     2   6  13    1    4   -1
   4     1     2     1     2  15  15    2    5   -1
   5     2     0     1     0  19   6    5    0    1
   6     2     2     1     1  11   6    4    5    0
   7     0     2     0     1   9  17    3    8   -1
   8     4     0     2     0  18   5    8    2    1
   9     0     0     0     0  18  16    3    6    0
```

Legenda dos dados:
FTHG (Full-Time Home Team Goals): quantos gols o time da casa fez na partida
FTAG (Full-Time Away Team Goals): quantos gols o time visitante fez na partida
HTHG (Half-Time Home Team Goals): quantos gols o time da casa fez até o intervalo
HTAG (Half-Time Away Team Goals): quantos gols o time visitante fez até o intervalo
HS (Home Team Shots): quantos chutes o time da casa deu ao gol do adversário
AS (Away Team Shots): quantos chutes o time visitante deu ao gol do adversário
HST (Home Team Shots on Target): quantos chutes o time da casa acertou
AST (Away Team Shots on Target): quantos chutes o time visitante acertou
FTR (Full-Time Result): resultado final da partida, com 0 indicando empate, 1 indicando vitória do time da casa e -1 indicando vitória do time visitante

Como eu poderia formar um coleção na qual um dos elementos é uma outra coleção para esse fim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na linha:

```
target.at[cont] = listaTarget
```

A variável **target** é do tipo Series. Quando você chama o **.at[cont]**, você está referenciando o elemento na posição **cont** da Series que é um valor único e não uma lista ou array. Está acontecendo de você está tentando adicionar uma lista/array/Series numa variável que só cabe um elemento único.

Para resolver isso você pode criar uma variável do tipo DataFrame e usar append/concat para adicionar novos elementos a ela.